# Regular expression to get the first match in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a text file inside it is:

```
"000000002|ROOT |237277309|000000003|ROOT |337277309|000000004|ROOT |437277309|"
```

Now I'm trying to use a regular expression to get the first chunk of number before '|ROOT ', the number is **000000002**.

I tried to use:

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = f.read()  
    x = re.findall("^\s*[0-9].(ROOT$)", lines)[0]

print(x)
```

And it does not work. My strategy is to get the string start with number and end with ROOT, and get the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROOT$` requires the four characters `ROOT` adjacent to the end of the line.  `findall` returns all matches; if you only care about the first, probably simply use `match` or `search`.

```py
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(r'(\d+)\|ROOT', line)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
            break
```

The `break` causes the loop to terminate as soon as the first match is found. We read one line at a time until we find one which matches, then terminate. (This also optimizes the program by avoiding the unnecessary reading of lines we do not care about, and by avoiding reading more than one line into memory at a time.) The parentheses in the regex causes the match inside them to be captured into `group(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Check out this code :**

```
import re
# 000000002|ROOT |237277309|000000003|ROOT |337277309|000000004|ROOT |437277309|

file = './file.txt'
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = f.read()  
    x = re.findall(r"(\d*[0-9])\|ROOT", lines)
    print(x)
    x = re.findall(r"(\d*[0-9])\|ROOT", lines)[0]
    print(x)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['000000002', '000000003', '000000004']
000000002
```